# How to serialize ObservableCollection in C#?

Tags: c#, observable

I have an observable collection say "OB" which needs to be serialized before it can be sent for print functionality.

I received the suggestion that to make it as a class as stated below

```
public class OBCollection : ObservableCollection<ViewModel>
{
}
```

And to use OBCollection in place of "OB" but this does not works.

Any suggestions on this?

I've tried below things:

- Marking the class as Serializable.
- Marking the observable collection as data member.
- Adding the parameterless constructor  in the class off which observable collection is the part.

Comment: " this does not works" is not very clear explanation of your problem. Note that it may be much easier to directly ask person who made "suggestion that to make it as a class as ...".

Comment: The above suggestion was provided as the guideline and the person is not available now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ObservableCollection<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` so you should be able to convert it to a `List<T>` or `T[]` simply enough with the `ToList()`/`ToArray()` extensions. Both of which can be serialized with the `DataContractSerializer` without issue (as long as the attributes a properly applied).